# Inertial frames and Rotation: shooting up a ball from a rotating platform

Tags: classical-mechanics, inertial-frames, rotational-kinematics, centrifugal-force, coriolis-effect

A short cylindrical tube is fixated in a horizontal platform and shoots a ball vertically in such a way that it falls back into the tube.

Now imagine that the platform is spinning with a certain constant angular velocity, and that the tube is at a distance $r$ from its center.
The picture bellow is a representation of the setup as seen from above. The shaded area is the area around the tube.

**How can I determine where the ball is going to fall?**

I assume it suffers a deviation and therefore it doesn't fall back in the tube. It is also quite easy to find the time of flight and the height the ball reaches, but my issue is I can't seem to visualise the coriolis and centrifugal forces on the platform's frame of reference. Plus, with no data whatsoever about the actual value of the angular velocity, I don't understand how we can predict the exact landing spot in the first place.

(**spoiler-alert**: the answer is in quadrant 2).

[image: Horizontal spinning platform]

Comment: Why don't you explain how you arrive at your spoiler answer (I'm not convinced it is correct, BTW).

Comment: The spoiler answer was in the professor's resolution of the problem. The issue is the resolution is confusing and unconvincing, there are a lot of conclusions he jumps to without previous fundamentation. Which is why I posted the problem in the first place

Comment: The body goes through regular projectile motion while the platform rotates underneath it. I am not sure what the difficulty is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question specifically asks about coriolis and centripetal forces, we will
work it that way.

The position vector

$r(t)=\{x(t),y(t),z(t)\}$

The angular velocity vector

$\omega0=\{0,0,\omega\}$

The coriolis force vector

$fcor=-2 m\ \omega0\times r'(t)$

which yields

$fcor=\{2 m\ \omega\  y'(t),-2 m\ \omega\ x'(t), 0\}$

The centripetal force vector

$fcent =-m\ \omega0\times (\omega0\times r(t))$

Gives us

$fcent=\{m\ \omega ^2 x(t),m\ \omega ^2 y(t),0\}$

The gravitational force

$fg=\{0,0,-m g\}$

Put it all together to get the equations of motion in the rotating coordinate system.

$m\ r''(t)=fcent+fcor+fg$

giving us

$x''(t)=\omega ^2 x(t)+2 \omega\  y'(t)\\
y''(t)=\omega ^2 y(t)-2 \omega\  x'(t)\\
z''(t)=-g$

Propel the ball from a distance $r0$ from the origin along the x axis. The initial conditions for the system are:

$x(0)=r0\\
x'(0)=0\\
y(0)=0\\
y'(0)=0\\
z(0)=0\\
z'(0)=v0$

Solve the system and we get

$x(t)=r0 (\omega\   t \sin  (\omega  t )+\cos  (\omega\   t ))\\
y(t)=r0 (t \omega  \cos (t\  \omega )-\sin (t\  \omega ))\\
z(t)=v0\ t-\frac{g\ t^2}{2}$

Calculate the time to fall back to the ground.

$tm=\frac{2 v0}{g}$

The landing position in the rotating frame.
$x(tm)=r0 (\frac{2 v0\  \omega  \sin (\frac{2 v0\  \omega }{g})}{g}+\cos (\frac{2 v0\ 
\omega }{g})\\
y(tm)=r0 (\frac{2 v0 \omega  \cos (\frac{2 v0\  \omega }{g})}{g}-\sin (\frac{2 v0 \omega
}{g}))$

Calculate the landing position in the intertial frame.
In addition to the velocity in the $z$ direction, the ball will have a $y$ velocity.

$vy=r0\ \omega $

$x$ will be constant

$x=r0\\
y=tm\ vy=\frac{2 r0\  v0\  \omega }{g}$

Convert this $x$ and $y$ to $x'$ and $y'$ for an axis rotation of $\theta = \omega\ tm$.

$x'=x \cos (\omega\ tm)+y\ \sin (\omega\  tm)=r0 (\frac{2 v0\  \omega  \sin (\frac{2 v0\  \omega }{g})}{g}+\cos (\frac{2 v0\ 
\omega }{g})\\
y'=y \cos (tm\ \omega )-x\ \sin (tm\ \omega )=r0 (\frac{2 v0 \omega  \cos (\frac{2 v0\  \omega }{g})}{g}-\sin (\frac{2 v0 \omega
}{g}))$

And through this simpler method we get the same result as through the coriolis and centripetal force equations.  I did use Mathematica to solve those equations.

Answer (score 3):

In this case using the centrifugal and coriolis expressions is an unnecessary difficult way to proceed.

Once the flight is underway there is no interaction with the platform. Therefore the motion relative to inertial space is a straight line. Given the velocity and time of flight you obtain the location relative to inertial space where the ball lands.

During the time of flight the platform has rotated trough an angle $\theta$
For example, let's say that the flight time was such that during flight time the platform has rotated through 135 degrees.

From the perspective shown the platform is rotating counterclockwise. To find the platform coordinates of the point of impact rotate the inertial space coordinate through 135 degrees, clockwise.

(It may be that your intention was to only consider flight times that are much shorter than the period of rotation of the platform. However, in your question you do not state that explicitly.)

Comment: Since the original problem doesn't explicetely state it, I decided not to include that in the post. But thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

In polar coordinates, Acceleration can be represented as,

$\vec a = (\ddot r - r \dot \theta^2)\hat r \; + \; (r \ddot \theta + 2\dot r \dot \theta)\hat \theta$

In this problem, (Interpreting OP's statement "certain angular velocity" as **constant** angular velocity)

And also, if we go into the non inertial rotating frame, then,

$\dot r = 0$ $\; \; ; \; \ddot r = 0$

And, the centripetal component ($-r\dot \theta ^2$ becomes positive)

We get, $\mathbf {\vec a = (r \dot \theta ^2)\hat r}$ (( In the non inertial frame))

The interpretation is that, in the rotating frame, the ball simply appears to move radially outwards from you.